# Webhooks triggered by Google Assistant

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I noticed that IFTTT.com is using a Google Assistant integration that allows them, basically, to set up for each of their users some kind of "trigger words" that trigger a call to a webhook. I searched a lot in the API docs and found no proper way to do the same, only ways to set up conversations or IoT interactions.

I kind of want to build something similar to the IFTTT integration with a way to programmatically set up actions via an API (not via the dashboard).

Is it possible to do or is this just a custom development Google made for IFTTT?

In my researches I found out about something called "Direct actions" but it does not seem to exist anymore in the Google Assistant Doc. Can you help me with that?

I don't know if my questions are very clear, please tell me if they are not

Thanks in advance for your help

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Here's similar options to the IFTTT integration:

- Create routines in the Google Home app. That will allow you to create custom commands that activate one or several actions.
- Create a [smart home action](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/). It's a type of direct action, as opposed to a conversational action, and will let you directly invoke the Assistant for a subset of commands.
- You could also create a [conversational action](https://developers.google.com/actions). While it would not give you the same direct control, you can still run actions quickly by doing a deeper invocation, ie. "Ask my test app to do an action". It would also give you much greater flexibility over the input.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your answer
Concerning the smart home actions, is it possible to set them up programmatically, I mean by accessing an API that tells: for user A I want commands X, Y that fulfill by triggering webhook 1 and for user B I want command Z that triggers webhook 2?

Comment: No. You'd get an access token to identify the user and a JSON request to a single webhook. But after that you'd be able to route things where you'd want.